# LED blinks even when I don't press the button

Tags: c, interrupts, stm32f0, gpio-external-interrupt, stm32cubemx

I have written a program in Keil that blinks a LED via External GPIO Interrupt. Here is how I have configured it in STM32CubeMX:

At first, I enabled and configured RCC as you can see and configured PA0 for external interrupt and PB1 as output.

[image: figure1]

For clock source, I configured it as you can see below.

[image: figure2]

And for Pins

[image: figure3]

[image: figure4]

I checked the "EXTI Line 0 and Line 1 interrupt" checkbox. I'm not sure that checking this checkbox is necessary.

[image: figure5]

After configuration, I generated the source code below (main.c):

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* System interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL12;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1);

  __SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/
```

For handling External GPIO Interrupt, I opened 'stm32f0xx_it.c' file and placed `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB , GPIO_PIN_1)` between `HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn)` and `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0)` then the interrupt source code is this:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f0xx.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_it.h"

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/

/******************************************************************************/
/*            Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers         */ 
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles System tick timer.
*/
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}

/**
* @brief This function handles EXTI Line 0 and Line 1 interrupts.
*/
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB , GPIO_PIN_1);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
}
```

I built the HEX file correctly and downloaded it to the MCU (without any problem or errors). Now, when I run it, there is a problem. The LED blinks quickly even when I don't press the button. Look:

[image: figure6]

[image: figure7]

Why? Also when I press the button, it toggles the LED but it blinks between each press. It looks like something changes the state of PB1 pin. What's the problem? How can I correct it?

Comment: I've never used that series of processors but noticed you have `GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL` you might need to change that to pull to ground (if available) or use an external resistor to pull it to ground. Not sure if there might be other problems but that's worth trying.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks Peter for reply. I already tryied it. I mean I already Pulled-up internal resistor (for nois) but that not work. in ST tutorials, they never use pull-up resistor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *must* either use the chip's internal pullup / pulldown resistor, or supply your own resistor.

You can also, at the same time, debounce the input by adding another smaller resistor and a small capacitor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwfHUB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The theory of operation is than when the switch is open the pullup / pulldown "pulls" the input pin to a known value.  If your switch connects the pin to ground, then a pullup resistor will connect the pin to \$+V_{CC}\$ when the switch isn't being pressed.  When the switch is pressed both the pin and the resistor are connected to ground, so the pin gets \$0V\$ and a small current (a few mA depending on voltage and resistance) flows through the resistor.

Comment: Thanks. When I pulled-down it (by a resistor externaly as you illustrated in figure), it works correctly!!! well done!

Comment: Also I have a simple problem now, it's bounce! How can I debounce it?

Comment: http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm

Comment: In some cases, for 5V they use 10nf for debounce but my MCU works by 3.3v. in your opinion, is the 10nf capacitor suitable for it?

Comment: I usually use 10K pullup, 100nF capacitor, and 100Ω discharge resistor.

Comment: "discharge resistor"? What's the usage of this resistor?

Comment: It discharges the capacitor slowly creating a smooth transition when you press the button.

Comment: If you add the Capacitor and the discharge resistor in the above schematic, it will be a great answer.